# implement click listener on recycler view fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

im using click listener on adapter like this

in adapter :

```
private var onItemClickListener: ((TansitionModel) -> Unit)? = null


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val article = differ.currentList[position]
    holder.itemView.apply {

        setOnClickListener { shit->
            onItemClickListener?.let {
                it(article)
            }
        }
    }
}


fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (TansitionModel) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener 
}
```

in fragement :

```
    financeTransitionAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {

        val extras = FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
            .addSharedElement(
                requireView().findViewById(R.id.imgsd),
                "trans").build()

        findNavController(requireView())
            .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_showTransitionFragment,
                null,
                null,
                extras
        )
    }
```

now with this architecture how can i pass multiple parameters like view and other data types (All together) from adapter click listener to fragment ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this architecture, you need to just change the receiver for the lambda you use. Maybe like this.

```
private var onItemClickListener: ((TansitionModel,String, View) -> Unit) = {_, _, _ ->} // maybe use it like this instead of making it null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (TansitionModel,String, View) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
```

And then call it with the aditional parameter. And you can then use them like this.

```
    financeTransitionAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { model, myString, view ->
        // use the variables
    }
```

However, i'd recommend using the interface approach as the other answer suggests

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full code of the adapter you are using but I will try to help with a piece of code from my project.

Firstly, what you need to do is create an interface like this:

```
interface AccountClickListener {
    fun onAccountClick(savedAccountModel: SavedAccountModel)
}
```

You can add as many parameters as you want to this function.

Now implement this interface in your adapter class constructor like this:

```
class ChangeAccountAdapter(
val context: Context,
val arrayList: ArrayList<SavedAccountModel>, 
val accountClickListener : AccountClickListener) 
: RecyclerView.Adapter<ChangeAccountAdapter.ChangeAccountHolder>(){
//your adapter class code
}
```

Your Holder Class should look something like this:

```
 inner class ChangeAccountHolder(val itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val imageView : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.savedaccountimg)
        init {
          imageView.setOnClickListener{accountClickListener.onAccountClick(arrayList[adapterPosition])}
    }
```

Now, you can implement your click listener in your activity or fragment like this:

```
class Profile : Fragment(), AccountClickListener{
    override fun onAccountClick(savedAccountModel: SavedAccountModel) {
    // Code for what you want to do on clicking the item.
    }
}
```

And at last, you can define your adapter like this :

```
  val adapter = ChangeAccountAdapter(requireContext(),modelList,this)
```

Comment: Nice approach, however, i like it better to implement the listener on it's own, without making the Fragment implement the Listener from the adapter.


`val listener = object : MyAdapter.OnItemClickedListener{
        override fun onItemClicked(item: Item) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
 } }`  
and then
 `myAdapter = MyAdapter(listener)`

Comment: tnks alot , your correct but i need in that architecture