# Fragment screen switching when clicking recycler view item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment

Fragment1 exists in MainActivity and Fragment2 exists in Fragment1.
Fragment2 contains a recycler view, and inside the recycler view there are items with a move button. When I click the go button, I want to switch to a screen other than the RcyclerView with the items currently displayed in Fragment2.

[image]

adpater

```
class Quality_Material_Certification(
    val material_name : String,
    val use_type : String,
    val standard : String,
    val material_num : String
)

class QualityMaterialCertificationAdapter(private val dataset: 
List<Quality_Material_Certification>) :RecyclerView.Adapter<QualityMaterialCertificationAdapter.QualityMaterialCertificationViewHolder>() {
class QualityMaterialCertificationViewHolder(val binding: 
ItemQualityMaterialCertificationBinding) : 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
QualityMaterialCertificationViewHolder {
      val view =LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_quality_material_certification, viewGroup, false)
    return QualityMaterialCertificationViewHolder(ItemQualityMaterialCertificationBinding.bind(view))
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: QualityMaterialCertificationViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val listposition = dataset[position]

    viewHolder.binding.materialName.text= listposition.material_name
    viewHolder.binding.useType.text = listposition.use_type
    viewHolder.binding.standard.text = listposition.standard

    viewHolder.binding.goToMoreBtn.setOnClickListener {
        setDataAtFragment(Fragment2(), listposition.material_num)
    }

}
override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size

private fun setDataAtFragment(fragment: Fragment, material : String)
{
    val bundle =  Bundle()
    val transaction = binding.root.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
    bundle.putString("material", material)
    fragment.arguments = bundle
    transaction?.replace(R.id.appro_fl, fragment)?.commit()
}
}
```

fragment1

```
private var token : String? = null
private var const_code : String? = null
private var list = arrayListOf<Quality_Material_Certification>()

class Fragment1 : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: 
FragmentQualityManagementFirefightingMaterialsCertificationBinding

var material: GetApproMaterListDTO? = null
lateinit var data: Quality_Material_Certification


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = FragmentQualityManagementFirefightingMaterialsCertificationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    binding.materialRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    binding.materialRecycler.adapter = QualityMaterialCertificationAdapter(list)

    arguments?.let {
        token = it.getString("token").toString()
        const_code = it.getString("cons_code").toString()
    }


    val dto = RequestDTO( "0", "9")

    retrofit.requestservice(sysCd, token.toString(), dto).enqueue(object :
        Callback<GetApproMaterListDTO> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetApproMaterListDTO>, t: Throwable) { Log.d("retrofit", t.toString()) }
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GetApproMaterListDTO>, response: Response<GetApproMaterListDTO>) {
            material = response.body()
            
            list.clear()
            
            for (i in 0 until material?.value?.list!!.size) {
                val material_name  = material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.material_name.toString()
                val use_type =  material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.use_type.toString()
                val standard = material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.standard.toString()
                val material_num = material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.material_num.toString()
                data = Quality_Material_Certification(material_name, use_type, standard ,material_num )
                list.add(data)
            }
            
            binding.materialRecycler.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            
        }
    })

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return binding.root
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
        Fragment1().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
            }
        }
}
```

}

modified comment opinion

apdapter

```
   interface clicktoDetail{
            fun onClickDetail(model : CertificationDTO)
        }

        class CertificationAdapter(
            private val context: Context,
            private val dataset: List<CertificationDTO>,
            private val clickListener: clicktoDetail)
            : RecyclerView.Adapter<QualityMaterialCertificationAdapter.ChangeHolder>() {

            inner class ChangeHolder(val binding: ItemCertificationBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
                //val btn :Button = button.findViewById(R.id.go_to_more_btn)
                init{
                    binding.goToMoreBtn.setOnClickListener { clickListener.onClickDetail(dataset[position]) }
                }
            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChangeHolder {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_certification, viewGroup, false)
                return ChangeHolder(ItemCertificationBinding.bind(view))
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ChangeHolder, position: Int) {
                val listposition = dataset[position]

                viewHolder.binding.materialName.text= listposition.material_name
                viewHolder.binding.useType.text = listposition.use_type
                viewHolder.binding.standard.text = listposition.standard
                viewHolder.binding.madeCompanyName.text = listposition.produce_co

         /* viewHolder.binding.goToMoreBtn.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(context, Fragment1::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("cons_code", listposition.project_const)
                    intent.run{
                        context.startActivity(this)
                        (context as Activity).finish()
                    }
                }*/
            }
            override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
        }
```

Fragment

```
private var token : String? = null
private var const_code : String? = null
private var material_list = arrayListOf<Quality_Material_CertificationDTO>()

class Certification_Fragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentQualityManagementFirefightingMaterialsCertificationBinding

var material: GetListDTO? = null
lateinit var material_data : Quality_Material_CertificationDTO


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    binding = FragmentCertificationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    val retrofitApproMaterList = RetrofitC("http://")
    val GetApproMaterListService: GetApproMaterListService = retrofitApproMaterList.create(GetListService::class.java)

    binding.materialRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    binding.materialRecycler.adapter = CertificationAdapter(requireContext(), material_list, GotoDetail())

    arguments?.let {
        token = it.getString("token").toString()
        const_code = it.getString("cons_code").toString()
    }

    val mdto = RequestDTO("", "")

    GetApproMaterListService.requestappromaterial(sysCd, token, mdto).enqueue(object :
        Callback<GetListDTO> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetListDTO>, t: Throwable) { Log.d("retrofit", t.toString()) }
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GetAListDTO>, response: Response<GetListDTO>) {
            material = response.body()
            material_list.clear()
            for (i in 0 until material?.value?.list!!.size) {
                val material_name  = material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.material_name.toString()
                val use_type =  material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.use_type.toString()
                val standard = material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.standard.toString()
                val produce_co  = material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.produce_co.toString()
                val material_num = material?.value?.list?.get(i)?.material_num.toString()
                material_data = Quality_Material_CertificationDTO(material_name, use_type, standard, produce_co ,material_num)
                material_list.add(material_data)
                CertificationAdapter(requireContext(), material_list, GotoDetail())
            }
            binding.materialRecycler.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
    
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    return binding.root
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
        Quality_Management_Firefighting_Materials_Certification_Fragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
            }
        }
}

class GotoDetail : Fragment(), clicktoDetail{
    override fun onClickDetail(model: Quality_Material_CertificationDTO) {
        val bundle =  Bundle()
        val transaction = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        bundle.putString("cons_code", const_code)
        bundle.putString("token", token)
        Fragment().arguments = bundle
        transaction?.replace(R.id.appro_fl, Certification_More_Fragment())!!.commit()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't share your code in a screenshot. Instead, copy your code and use code block quotations to format it as code.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I wrote it by following the material you sent me. But when onClickListener is fired, NullPointerException is thrown in "transaction.replace" part. Is this a different issue? What I want is to replace the Flagment frame that currently contains the recycler view with another Flagment when each item is clicked. Is there a way? I'll post the code if you want.

Comment: transaction?.replace(R.id.appro_fl, Certification_More_Fragment())!!
By using "!!" You are asserting that your statement is not null which it is not. Don't assert not null when you are not sure if it won't be null. It is hence giving you null pointer exception

Comment: Instead of activity use requireActivity()

Comment: Why do you have a GoToDetail fragment inside another fragment? That is wrong

Comment: You have so many ? safe null calls in your code. I am not sure if it is a good practice to have so many of them but it just looks difficult to look at. Also it is definitely more difficult to type so many "?". Instead try handling null pointer exception yourself by using if else

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access activities and fragments inside your adapter class which is incorrect. Never do that! Instead, create an item click listener and create a reference to it in your activity. This way you can handle item click in your activity and perform fragment transactions.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73176945/14700539), You can take help on how to do so by making an onClickInterface